# pass string array as parameter to asp.net mvc webapi method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using webapi2 and here is my client side code

```
var tbody = $('#files-table').find('tbody'); // tbody where all rows exists 
        var sortOrder = $(tbody).sortable('toArray').toString(); // geting ids of all rows 
        var updateSortOrder = $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl + 'mycontroller/updateimagesorder',
            dataType: 'json',
            traditional: true,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify({ "sortOrder": sortOrder.split(',') }),
            type: 'PUT'
        });
        updateSortOrder.done(function (result) {
            closeModel('images-model');
        });
```

and here is my server side method

```
[Route("updateimagesorder")]
    public HttpResponseMessage PutImagesSortOrder([FromBody]string[] sortOrder) 
    {
       // do stuff with parameters 
     }
```

Note : **/mycontroller** is route prefix here and `baseUrl` is my domain url

so , what the issue in my code ?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? Any error? Any unexpected behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing the value like this:

```
data: JSON.stringify(sortOrder.split(',')),
```

So that your request payload looks like a string array:

```
["foo", "bar"]
```

If you want to pass the value like that:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ "sortOrder": sortOrder.split(',') }),
```

then make sure that you have declared a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string[] SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will take as parameter:

```
[Route("updateimagesorder")]
public HttpResponseMessage PutImagesSortOrder(MyViewModel model) 
{
    // do stuff with parameters 
}
```